# can multiple users share ClearCase snapshot view?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

In a ClearCase and RAD environment instead of creating multiple workspaces and views for multiple users, can we create a set of workspaces and views per functionality and share this across multiple developers by updating the configurations like config_spec.

Btw, the views that i would like to share are Snapshot views created on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the views, the short answer is yes: you don't have to be the owner of the views to checkout them. But that will certainly work for read-access (and need to be tested for write/checkin cases).

But regarding RAD workspaces, it is best that each developer maintains his/her own one, configured to access the right common view.

Comment: i updated my initial question to include that these views are snapshot views created on network drive.

Comment: @iab. as long as the network drive is accessible from all users, and their CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP is the same as the group protecting that view, it should be easy to share it. Note: its view *storage* (.vws) needs also to be accessible by all.

Comment: got it. Do i have make any other updates to config spec or any other configuration files? how it will recognize the UUID?

Comment: @iab. if it is the same view shared by all, no update is necessary.

Comment: got it. how about the version history? each person will have their own history when checked out and checked in from the same view?

Comment: @iab. The checkout will be one for every user. But the checkin part will need for the view to be updated: in case of concurrent checkin, only the first one will produce a new version, the other ones will need to merge (which will happen during the update). Still I don't recommend sharing a view for concurrent modification: it should be for read-only purpose.

Comment: that's how i understood initially but in our environment we are looking to enhance the process so that the developers wanting to setup the workspace doesn't have to go through multiple steps which is a time consuming process so i'm looking into different options like this one.   
 this is how my environment is we have each snapshot view created for each developer per each functionality and has it's respective RAD workspace and to do all this it take about half a day for each developer.